# nodejs setinterval convert to real time

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, timer

I am building small multiplayer game and iam having hard time to grasp `setInterval` configuration. Lets say that i want to give players abilities that will run on cooldown or spawn certain objects in actual time interval (like every 5 seconds or have 2 seconds cool down). The problem is that I cannot sync server `setInterval` loop with real time concept.

for example i have this loop that runs cooldowns:

```
setInterval(function() {
    game.mechanics.buffered.cooldowns.run();
}, 10);
```

I have notices that if I lower this `10` value, cooldowns run faster, if i put it to higher number, they run slower, but i have no idea how to sync it for real time. I dont even know what value should be put there in server loop in the first place, i am happy with `10ms` so far but real time cooldowns wont work with it currently.

Logic points that `setTimeout` would be more proper solution for spawning and such but `setInterval` gives me possibility of providing progress bar while `setTimeout` does not.

The question would be, how to properly configure this loop so then i can say in cooldown object that it lasts 2 seconds and it will be executed after those 2 seconds.

Comment: `The problem is that I cannot sync server setInterval loop with real time concept.` - huh? there's always `Date.now()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not perfect solution, but it gets you started.

```
var last = 0,
    current = 0,
    tick = 10,
    seconds = 3;

setInterval(function() {
    current += tick;
    if(current - last >= seconds * 1000) {
        last = current;
        console.log(new Date().getSeconds());
    }
}, tick);
```

Comment: yes in console log it can be noticed that it skips sometimes (like misses 1 second) but it indeed is an idea how to go with it.